# Change the color of OverFlow Menu

Tags: java, android, overflow-menu

This is my Starting Activity. It is working fine programmatically.

The only problem which I'm facing is that the OverFlow-Menu comes is dark theme when called by the Hardware Menu key.

I've provided all the essential lines of code in this sample.

```
public class StartingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginActivity_Tab.loginActivityTab_interface {

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://rollhack.96.lt/login.php";
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting);

    includeWidgets();
}

private void includeWidgets() {

    /////   Tab Layout   /////

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    /////   ToolBar     /////

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("Note Pad");
}

/////   This method is called for Exiting the App   /////
public void exitApp() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder exit = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartingActivity.this);
    exit.setTitle("Exit Application")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit the application?")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    StartingActivity.this.finishAffinity();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null);
    exit.create().show();
}

/////   This method is called to assign the Key Events  /////
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            exitApp();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_starting_activity, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(null);
        case (R.id.menu_about):
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(null);
        case (R.id.menu_exit):
            exitApp();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is how it looks when it is called by the overflow menu icon of the ActionBar

[image]

This is how my App OverFlow-Menu looks when Hardware Menu key is pressed

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overflow menu by Icon**

You can change the color of the overflow menu background  by adding a new style in style.xml.

```
 <style name="OverflowMenu"
   parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
 <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyOverflowMenu</item>
 <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="MyOverflowMenu" 
   parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/your_color</item> 
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

**Overflow Menu by Hardware Key**

To change the color of Overflow menu called by Hardware key, add another style.

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/OverflowMenuHardware</item>
  </style>

  <style name="OverflowMenuHardware" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/your_color</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/your_color</item>
  </style>
```

Implement either one of these to change the color of Overflow menu of either the one called by icon(former code) or by hardware key(latter code).

Comment: Can you describe it bit more?
Well I tried what you suggested me but nothing beneficial happen. The App is acting same as before.

Comment: You want to change the overflow menu color right? The given code does that. Set the color of overflow menu background same as the color of the one called by hardware key.

Comment: Check the edited code. You can change either of the background colors.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it worked for me. Apart from this, just adding a single line

        `<item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>`

also worked.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!